# How do I use linq to get the difference of a List<byte[]> and an anonymous type with a byte[] property?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am new to Linq and extension methods and I guess I just can't grasp the use of all the extension methods yet.

I am reading a bunch of files, and after one has been read, I'm storing the hash value of the file into a database (the file names change, and they are moved around). Periodically, I want to check a directory and read any files that I have not already, based on their hash value. So, I added an extension method to get the SHA256 hash of a file:

```
public static byte[] GetSHA256Hash(this FileInfo file)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (SHA256 hasher = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            return hasher.ComputeHash(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I query my database and get a list of hashes that I have already read, check the directory for all files and then I want to figure out which ones aren't in the list of files I've read. I'm positive that the byte[] in filesRead match the hashes returned by my extension method.

```
//Get list of hashes that have been read
List<byte[]> filesRead = GetReadFiles();

// I also need the file name, directory, etc so I can pass 
// that info on to the next method that actually reads the file
var filesOnDisk = (new DirectoryInfo("c:\\dirtocheck").GetFiles("*"))
    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime > new DateTime(2009, 01, 01))
    .Select(fileinfo => new { File = fileinfo, Hash = fileinfo.GetSHA256Hash() });

var filesToProcess = filesOnDisk
    .Where(file => !filesRead.Contains(file.Hash))
    .Select(fileinfo => fileinfo.File).ToList<FileInfo>();
```

My problem is that none of the files are filtered out. I've compared the hashes in filesRead to the hashes of files in filesToProcess and they match. I just don't get it.

Comment: Two different byte array references never compare as equal even if they contain the same bytes. Perhaps you should be using the SequenceEquals extension method to compare the two byte arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah what Eric said. filesRead.Contains is not going to do what you expect. Try introducing a new structure or class that [implements equality](http://ikriv.com:8765/en/prog/info/dotnet/ObjectEquality.html) so the contains does not do a refrence comparison and instead does a value comparison.

Comment: Arg! I was blinded by the LINQ!